# Emploi du subjonctif (parler pour le passé)

Tags: usage, subjonctif

Lors d'une présentation (public académique) et parlant pour son parcours peut-on employer l'imparfait du subjonctif du verbe être

> En Grèce bien que je fusse étudiant, je cherchais toujours à...

ou est-ce mieux d'utiliser le passé du subjonctif de l'usage courant

> En Grèce bien que j'aie été étudiant, je cherchais toujours à...

La structure ci-après a-t-elle le même sens :

> En Grèce même si j'étais étudiant, je cherchais toujours à...

Comment: A qui s'adresse la présentation ? Dans quel contexte ? Cela dictera la réponse.

Comment: @Greg : Présentation qui s'adresse aux Professeurs (université).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le subjonctif passé est tellement courant qu'il sera accepté dans la très grande majorité des contextes, même académiques, le subjonctif imparfait ayant largement disparu de l'usage oral et, à l'écrit, étant plutôt d'usage littéraire.

Pour une présentation devant des professeurs d'université, je n'utiliserais le subjonctif imparfait que si c'est une présentation très formelle (par exemple une séance d'ouverture de l'année académique), où vous lirez votre discours plutôt que parler spontanément de votre parcours. Mais par contre, si vous décidez de l'utiliser, veillez alors à l'utiliser de manière cohérente avec le registre du reste de votre discours (en utilisant par exemple le passé simple et en gardant le subjonctif imparfait/plus-que-parfait partout).

Comment: C'est noté:-)! Merci. Dernière question. La tournure ...même si j'étais étudiant (évitant comme ça le subjonctif) a le même sens ?

Comment: Dans cette phrase, le sens est le même (*même si* donne peut-être une nuance d'opposition un peu plus forte).

Comment: D'accord:-)! Merci bien !